# using expo push notification, iOS device cannot receive push

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

My iPhone cannot receive push notification from my expo app.

1. I checked Device Token must be made.
2. I already checked notification permission.
3. Other Expo Push Test apps also not work
4. My iPhone can receive push from Other apps

What should I do? is Expo's problem?

Comment: Hi, can you share your code

Comment: Oops! I figured out foreground state in application cannot show notification before now. I fixed!! Thank you!